# Ajax tabs with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a menu tab in jQuery, but I have one especific tab to be loaded only when the tab is accessed.

What is happening now is: the jQuery tab works normal, BUT, this especific tab what I said is very very detrimental to the page load, so I want load it when the user click.

My current code in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Quando a página carrega...
$(".tab_content").hide(); // Esconde todo o conteúdo
$("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); // Ativa a primeira aba
$(".tab_content:first").show(); // Mostra o conteúdo da primeira aba

// Evento ao clicar
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); // Remove toda classe "ativa"
    $(this).addClass("active"); // Adiciona a classe "ativa" na aba
    $(".tab_content").hide(); // Esconde todo o conteúdo da aba

    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); // Procura o atributo href para selecionar o conteúdo e a aba
    $(activeTab).show(); // Fade na aba ativa

    return false;
   });
});
```

The list of tabs:

```
                <ul class="tabs">
                            <li><a href="#user-posts">posts</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#user-profile">perfil</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#user-gallery">galeria</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#user-friends">amigos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#user-mp">mensagens pessoais</a></li>
                </ul>
```

The conatiner of tabs:

```
                <div class="tab_container">
                    <?php include("includes/posts/posts.inc.php"); ?>
                    <?php include("includes/infos.inc.php"); ?>
                    <?php include("includes/amigos.inc.php"); ?>
                    <?php include("includes/galeria.inc.php"); ?>
                    <?php include("includes/mps.inc.php"); ?>
                </div>
```

How can I adapt this jQuery to AJAX?

Thank you!

Comment: Which tab is the one in question? Show us the html please?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Evento ao clicar
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); // Remove toda classe "ativa"
    $(this).addClass("active"); // Adiciona a classe "ativa" na aba
    $(".tab_content").hide(); // Esconde todo o conteúdo da aba

    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"), // Procura o atributo href para selecionar o conteúdo e a aba
        $activeTab = $(activeTab); // Objeto jQuery em cache

    // Se a guia requer ajax
    if ( $activeTab.data('load') ) {

        $.ajax({
            url: $activeTab.data('load'),
            success: function( data ) {
                $activeTab.html(data).show();
            }
        });

    } else {
        $activeTab.show(); // Fade na aba ativa
    }

    return false;
});
```

Then in your HTML add a data attribute.

```
<li data-load="http://www.example.com/your/url.html">Content</li>
```

The `.data()` method will look for all `data-` attributes. In the `if` statement I'm checking to see if the `data-load` attribute exists on each activeTab. If it does it will make an ajax request and when that comes back successfully it will load the content into the active tab and then show it.

If it doesn't have `data-load` then it will just show the content.

Comment: Hello, @Seth. Very my for you reply, really! But, if I need to do something like this: "<li data-load="includes/galeria.inc.php"><a href="#">galeria</a></li>", do not work. :/ What I have to do? Thank you again, Seth! Peace.

Comment: Are you saying you can't edit the HTML or the above code doesn't work when you added the `data-load` URL?

Comment: Well, @Seth, thanks for the reply again. So, I don't know. I don't know if the way I showed you above is right, because I never worked with data load, but anyway, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to roll your own tab navigation? You should take a look at the [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/), if you haven't come across it already.

You can achieve what you want to do in a much simpler and, perhaps, more robust fashion. For example, if you want to have static pages for posts and profile, and load the gallery via AJAX, you can do something like this:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#user-posts">posts</a></li>
        <li><a href="#user-profile">perfil</a></li>
        <li><a href="url/to/galeria.php">galeria</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="user-posts">
        <?php include("includes/posts/posts.inc.php"); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="user-profile">
        <?php include("includes/infos.inc.php"); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in your JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
```

Comment: Hello, William. Thanks! So, this is an AJAX solution? I don't understand.

Comment: @GO, I included a link to jQuery UI Tabs demo page. Go ahead and try it out. It handles all AJAX interaction for you; you just needed to include an actual link instead of an in-page anchor (as shown in the code).